# Face recognition in javascript using face api getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'descriptor' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, typeerror, face-recognition

Facing this issue in the implementation of face recognition on the webcam camera for the browser using node js for the web application. This error only comes when I add more than 1 name in my labels in loadLabeledImages() function. If I have one name, it works perfectly fine. Beginner here and I have been getting the same error for days now

If I log Resized detections and detections, I get this:
[Error after logging detections and resized detections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckDQy.png)

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

```
setInterval(async () => {
const detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(video).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor()
const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
this.labeledFaceDescriptors = await this.loadLabeledImages()
const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(labeledFaceDescriptors, 0.6)
const results = resizedDetections.map(d => faceMatcher.findBestMatch(d.descriptor))
results.forEach((result, i) => {
  const box = resizedDetections[i].detection.box
  const drawBox = new faceapi.draw.DrawBox(box, {label: result.toString()})
  drawBox.draw(canvas) 
})

}, 100) 
})

function loadLabeledImages() {

try{
const labels = ['Jane', 'Alex']

return Promise.all(
  labels.map(async label => {
    const descriptions = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      const img = await faceapi.fetchImage(`public/img/${label}/${i}.jpg`)
      const detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor()
      descriptions.push(detections.descriptor)
    }

    return new faceapi.LabeledFaceDescriptors(label, this.descriptions)
  })
)

    }
   catch(err){
     console.log(err)
     }

       }
```

Comment: Try to log ```detections(in the for loop in loadLabeledImages function)``` and ```resizedDetections(in the setInterval function)``` and check the values. Check the return type of the functions from which you are assigning values to these variables

Comment: I tried logging the two as you said, and detections is an object once and undefined the next time. I edited my question and added an image of the error. I am not really sure what is happening. Thank you for your help

Comment: Try to ```JSON.stringify()``` to see actual data while logging. And also check if the ```img``` is not null or undefined.

Comment: Using JSON.stringify converts the Object:Object outputs so the long x and y number data that its suppose to have for resized detections and detections. And every other detection is undefined. img is not null, I had already checked that before and it works perfectly if I only keep one name in the labels array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the delay, my problem was solved by changing the images. The error was because it could not identify a face (descriptor) in the images provided by me. I checked the quality of the images, which was very bad so I changed them to a good quality image and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

'descriptor' value is undefined..hence you are getting error

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I tried to google everything about undefined errors but nothing seems to work. I am giving it value and it works perfectly fine with one person. But it returns undefined when it runs with multiple people. I don't know why it is undefined and what I can do to fix it. Thank you for your reply